# List of generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class and I want to create a list of it. and then at run time I get the type of the item

#### Class

```
public class Job<T>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Task<T> Task { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    public bool Repeat { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset NextExecutionTime { get; set; }

    public Job<T> RunOnceAt(DateTimeOffset executionTime)
    {
        NextExecutionTime = executionTime;
        Repeat = false;
        return this;
    }
}
```

#### What I want to achive

```
List<Job<T>> x = new List<Job<T>>();

public void Example()
{
    //Adding a job
    x.Add(new Job<string>());

    //The i want to retreive a job from the list and get it's type at run time
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If all of your jobs are of same type (e.g. `Job<string>`) you can simply create a list of that type:

```
List<Job<string>> x = new List<Job<string>>();
x.Add(new Job<string>());
```

However, if you want to mix jobs of different types (e.g. `Job<string>` and `Job<int>`) in the same list, you'll have to create a non-generic base class or interface:

```
public abstract class Job 
{
    // add whatever common, non-generic members you need here
}

public class Job<T> : Job 
{
    // add generic members here
}
```

And then you can do:

```
List<Job> x = new List<Job>();
x.Add(new Job<string>());
```

If you wanted to get the type of a `Job` at run-time you can do this:

```
Type jobType = x[0].GetType();                       // Job<string>
Type paramType = jobType .GetGenericArguments()[0];  // string
```

Comment: Small question, how could I add a job<string> to that list then ?

Comment: And sorry could you explain it a little more by adding what would be instead of { ... }

Comment: The abstract class is just an empty class or what ?

Comment: @ErricJManderin That will depend on what exactly you need from a `Job` and from a `Job<string>`, but looking at your code it seems you could have any everything but `Task` and `RunAtOnce` in the non-generic `Job` class.

Comment: Ok another question sorry :D, when retrieving a job from the list how to restore it's generic type ? in other words how to know if it were a Job<string> or <int> or whatever ?

Comment: You don’t really need to create a `Job` type though. Just a `Job<T>` is good enough…

Comment: @ErricJManderin If you really go with a `List<Job>` then you can only check the type for each object manually (just as if you had a `List<object>`), e.g. `if (obj is Job<string>) { var stringJob = (Job<string>) obj); }`

Comment: @ErricJManderin The job never looses it's type, so 'restoring' it doesn't really make any sense. If you need to access some generic member you can do a simple cast: `((Job<string>)job).Task`.

Answer (score 7):

By making an interface and implement it in your class you will be able to create a list of that interface type,adding any job :

```
interface IJob
{
    //add some functionality if needed
}

public class Job<T> : IJob
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Task<T> Task { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    public bool Repeat { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset NextExecutionTime { get; set; }

    public Job<T> RunOnceAt(DateTimeOffset executionTime)
    {
        NextExecutionTime = executionTime;
        Repeat = false;
        return this;
    }
}

List<IJob> x = new List<IJob>();
x.Add(new Job<string>());
```